# Access the contents of a column in a DataTable in code

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

I've done research on this but none of results found does what I'm looking for.

Suppose I have a DataTable that was filled from a MySql database, in another function, I want to access one of the columns and assign the values to a variable (one at time in a loop)

Some code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim intList As New List(Of Integer)
.......
.......
adapter.fill(dt)
.......
.......
dim col = dt.Columns(1)
populate the list here with the contents of the column
```

**EDIT** I am not entirely sure that `Columns(1)` is correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Referring to the other answer) First, note that there is no need to separately declare scratch variables used to loop thru something.  You can declare the type as part of the `For...`:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In Dt.Rows
```

This is a more than a matter of coding style.  The `row` variable above exists only between the `For Each` and `Next`.  Declared as in the other answer, a more lengthy method can result in `tmp`, `tmp1` etc each of a different type which were used just once for different loops.

Then, there are a number of linq methods that can get your list for you without you writing a loop at all:

```vb
Dim carbs = dt.AsEnumerable().
                  Select(Function(q) q.Field(Of Int32)("Carbs")).
                  ToList()
```

With `Option Infer`, you don't even need to declare `carbs` as a `List(of Int32)`, but you can:

```vb
Dim carbs As List(Of Int32) = dt.AsEnumerable(). ...
```

Comment: This works very, very well. I just don't understand how the select function works by using a function in the argument. Any sources you recommend on reading to understand that further?

Comment: It is a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).  It provides the actual logic for *what* to select.   Many, many of the linq methods will take/or require a lambda to supply the actual logic.  Note that `q.Field(Of ...)` is yet another linq extension to cast the column selected to a specific type.  Together they can reduce simple loops to almost nothing or perform  much more complex tasks with very little code.  [This is a c# example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39082249/1070452) to remove dupes in 2 CSV files ( `q =>` is the c# form of `Function (q)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Plutonix , I'll make sure I go over all of this this weekend, it looks like I can reduce a lot of my code using this

Comment: The starting point is probably  [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), then lambdas as needed to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747004/get-value-from-datatable), I don't know how I missed that in my seach.

The code in the end is the following:

```
    Dim carbsInvolved As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each row In dt.Rows
        carbsInvolved.Add(row.Item(1))
    Next
```

And then the numbers in the list can be accessed by `carbsInvolved.Item(index)` for later use :)